# Usage of Boolean Variable in Constructor

Tags: java

I am studying these codes below got from a website (source: https://gist.github.com/allisons/842546). Can anyone please explain the usage of the variable __processCalled? I don't get why it is put in the constructor and how it affects the process method (in both subclass and super class). It seems to me that this boolean variable is assigned values but is not actually used (like in the if statement:  if (__processCalled) {}).
Thank you so much for your help!

//Provided Code

```
public class Account {
    public boolean __processCalled; 
    public Account(Client c) {
        __processCalled = false;
    }

    public boolean process(Transaction t) {
        __processCalled = true;
        return t.value() > -100 && t.value() < 1000000;
    }

    public class Client {}

    public class Transaction {
        private int value;  

        public Transaction(int v) {
             value = v;
        }

        public int value() {
             return value;
        }
    }
}
```

//My Code

```
public class FilteredAccount extends Account{

    private boolean __processCalled;
    private int filteredCount;
    private int transactionCount; 

    public FilteredAccount(Client c) {
       super(c);
       __processCalled = false; 
       filteredCount = 0;
       transactionCount = 0;
    }

    public boolean process(Transaction t){
        transactionCount++; 
        __processCalled = true;

        if(t.value == 0){
             filteredCount++;
             return true;
        }else{
             return super.process(t);
        }  
  }

  public double percentFiltered(){
      if(transactionCount == 0){
           return 0.0;
      }

      return filteredCount/transactionCount *100;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code breaks naming convention FYI

Comment: It doesn't affect anything.  It's just there so that you can check to see if an account has been processed or not (that's why it's public).

Comment: @ngocduong Why are you studying 6 year old code which seems to have been of poor quality even during the day it was made?